# How to cent image buttons vertically on the action bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made a custom theme to display my image buttons on the action bar. I was wondering how I can center these buttons vertically in android.

The code I have written so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/groups" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center|fill_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/contactlist" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right|center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/favourites" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This is what I want

[image]

Comment: check it out my answer.tested ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/groups" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/contactlist" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/favourites" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image buttons inside a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation, and then set their gravity to `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: If a use a LinearLayout then I can put the image buttons to the left,right and center.  I don't want to hard-code any margin values

Comment: @user123456 can you post a screenshot or drawing of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yea I just uploaded an image of what I want

Comment: Why don't you use Tabs instead? See http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

Comment: If I use tabs, then I can't use the ListAdapter, to display a list. So I have to use the action bar

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FE6602" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center|fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#DBEAF9" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FAF2B0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Changes:**

```
android:layout_height="50dip" to  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:background="#FE6602" to android:background="@drawable/contactlist"
```

I just put simple color and static size or testing purpose work like charm.